# Why did the Haskell committee choose monads to represent I/O?

Tags: functional-programming, history, haskell

The [Clean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_%28programming_language%29) language uses [uniqueness types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_type) to handle I/O in a purely functional setting. Why did the Haskell committee go with [monads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monads_in_functional_programming) instead? Were there other proposals for handling state that the committee investigated but decided against?

<sub>**Note**: I'm not looking for a holy war between monads and other forms of computing. Let's keep the topic to just the committee's choices regarding I/O.</sub>

Comment: Related: [Why monads? How does it resolve side-effects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840126/why-monads-how-does-it-resolve-side-effects)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [A History of Haskell: Being Lazy With Class](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/history-of-haskell/history.pdf) (see section 7) three different models were considered initially: **streams**, **continuations** and **"world passing"** (I don't know much about Clean, but it sounds like this is the Clean way?).

The last paragraph of section 7.2 indicates that the **uniqueness type** concept wasn't developed at this time:

> This “world-passing” model was never a
>       serious contender for Haskell, however, because we saw no easy
>       way to ensure “single-threaded” access to the world state. (The
>       Clean designers eventually solved this problem through the use
>       of “uniqueness types”)

The concept of monads seems to have been introduced (reused from other work) in later revisions of Haskell since it resulted in cleaner code (compared to continuations/streams):

> The monadic approach rapidly dominated earlier models. The types are
>   more compact, and more informative.

Answer (score 10):

The best explanation I've seen is Simon Peyton-Jones' "[Tackling the Awkward Squad](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/marktoberdorf/)."

From what I remember from the paper, issues around laziness played a big part in the decision. (I'm not sure if Clean is lazy by default the same way Haskell is.)

Comment: Clean is lazy too.